# Two separate template profile pages for user his/herself and other users?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Since profile pages should be editable for the user himself/herself,

should I determine the profile owner in view and have a different template just for other users viewing the same page

or

should I use template tags determining whether the current user is the profile owner?

I'm a newb to web app development and Django. Sorry if the question is too broad. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use a single template and check if user is authenticated in your template and display the necessary code for logged-in users.**

To check if user is authenticated in a template, use `user.is_authenticated`. But, remember that the [`auth` context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) has to be enabled in the settings for the current `user` to be present in the template context.

You can pass a `user_id` kwarg in the url to access that user's profile page. You can define your urls something like:

```
url(r'^user/profile/(?P<user_id>\w+)/$', ProfilePage.as_view(), name='profile_page'),
```

Then in your `views`, you can pass the `requested_profile_id` in the context.

```
Class ProfilePage(..):

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(ProfilePage, self).get_context_data()
        # pass user id for which profile page was requested
        context['requested_profile_id'] = self.kwargs.get('user_id') 
        return context
```

Then in your templates, check if current user's `id` is same as the `requested_profile_id`. If it is same, then you can display the portion to edit profile. You can do something like:

**my_template.html**

```
...
<!-- your normal code here -->
..
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.id==requested_profile_id %}
    ...
    <!-- your code for current user profile edit page here -->
    ..
{% endif %}
```

Comment: How can I tell if the user is viewing his/her own profile or someone else is viewing his/her profile?

Comment: You can check if current user `id` is same as the `id` of the person whose profile page he has requested. If it is true, you can display the profile edit portion in your template. Updated the ans with the same.

Answer (score 0):

You show the himself/herself users profile data  based on their userid,so single  profile template is enough.
Example:

```
def profile(request,userid)
    .......
    return render_to_response('profile.html',{..context..})
```

Comment: Does that mean I need template tags such {% if %} to determine what to display to the user? For example, the edit button, 
if the user is viewing himself/herself own profile page, display the edit button?